# access a property of an object in another classes function

Tags: c#, object

Hey stackoverflow users,

Got a quick one

I'm trying to access a property of an object in another classes function , I can't seem to get it working.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        User PIE = new User();
        Userchanger changer = new Userchanger();
        changer.ChangeToFailedUser(PIE); //this won't work - The best overloaded method match for 'ConsoleApplication1.Userchanger.ChangeToFailedUser(ref object)' has some invalid arguments   

    }
}

public class User
{
    public string Username = "Firstname.Lastname";
}

public class Userchanger
{
    public void ChangeToFailedUser (ref object PIE) 
    {
        object PIEThingy = PIE;
        PIEThingy.Username = "AnotherFN.AnotherLN"; //So how do I actually access the object User's Username string variable? It's more important that I can GET the variable rather than edit it.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should add a `ref` keyword when you passing a parameter as a *ref parameter*

```
changer.ChangeToFailedUser(ref PIE);
```

See [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx)

> To use a **ref** parameter, both the method definition and the *calling method* must explicitly use the ref keyword, as shown in the following example.

And `object` class doesn't contain `Username` property.To access your property you should use a `cast`, or use `as` operator to avoid `InvalidCastException`

```
 User PIEThingy = PIE as User;

 if(PIEThingy != null) PIEThingy.Username = "AnotherFN.AnotherLN";
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use `ref` to update a class instance. It's passed by reference, by default.

Just change the signature on your method to accept a `User` instead of `ref object`.

```
public class Userchanger
{
    public void ChangeToFailedUser (User PIE) 
    {
        PIE.Username = "AnotherFN.AnotherLN";
    }
}
```

On the other hand, primitive types such as `int` are passed by value. You can use the `ref` keyword to specify that any changes you make to the passed-in parameter are also made to the variable back in the calling method.

Answer (score 1):

You have created property in `User` class why are you expecting it in instance of `object`. Also instance of class is by default passed by reference so no need of `ref`